# Multiple file selection from different directories using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, multipleselection

I have an issue while using `JFileChooser` class in Java. I want to select multiple files from different directories and I don't know if it's possible using this class.

I know there's the method `setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)` that enables multi-selection but it's just multi selection in the same directory.
How can I choose multiple files (at least two) from different directories in the same `JFileChooser` window?

This is the class that I am actually using:

```
public class DialogFileGraph extends JPanel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 449534361312105564L;
    /**
     * String constant for new line
     */
    private static final String NEWLINE = "\n";
    /**
     * empty constant for filename
     */
    private static final String EMPTY = "empty";
    /**
     * logger
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DialogFileGraph.class);
    /**
     * 
     */
    private final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    /**
     * 
     */
    private String file = EMPTY;
    /**
     * @param filepath
     *        path to the file
     * @param compare
     *        Boolean
     */
    public DialogFileGraph(File filepath, Boolean compare) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        try{
            fc.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("NetCDF files", "nc"));
            if (!compare){
                // Case for choosing one file
                fc.setCurrentDirectory(filepath);
                fc.setDialogTitle(Messages.DialogFileGraph_File_Choice);
                fc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
                fc.setEnabled(true);
                fc.setLocation(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint());
                fc.setVisible(true);
                fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                final int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    final File realFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
                    file = realFile.getAbsolutePath();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        Messages.DialogFileGraph_Open_Cancelled + NEWLINE);
                    file = EMPTY;
                }
            } else {

                // Case for choosing multiple files
                fc.setCurrentDirectory(filepath);
                fc.setDialogTitle(Messages.DialogFileGraph_Multi_Files_Choice);
                fc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
                fc.setEnabled(true);
                fc.setLocation(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint());
                fc.setVisible(true);
                fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

                final int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    final File[] realFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                    for(int i=0;i<realFiles.length-1;i++){
                        file = realFiles[i].getAbsolutePath()+";"+realFiles[i+1].getAbsolutePath();
                    }

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        Messages.DialogFileGraph_Open_Cancelled + NEWLINE);
                    file = EMPTY;
                }
            }
        } catch (HeadlessException ex){
            LOGGER.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
     * invoked from the event dispatch thread.
     * @return String file
     */
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you select files from multiple directories and do , `fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();`

Comment: You can't select files from multiple directories, when I select a file and change the directory, even while holding 'Ctrl' button, it doesn't keep it selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just about the same question from 2012: [Link](https://coderanch.com/t/562332/java/JFileChooser-selecting-multiple-files-directories)
As you can see in this post, you need to let the user choose files multiple times and add them to an array each time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Campiotti. I've already tried integrating this solution but it's not working. I only get the last chosen file registered in the array.

Comment: Are you sure you're implementing it correctly? (sorry for the late reply btw)

I see `final File[] realFiles = fc.getSelectedFiles();` in your code, however that will obviously only return the last chosen files because you use a `final` as well as a `=` in that statement. 
Shouldn't you be adding all the files to an array and then finally returning / using that array?